# Funcionamiento de emmet y !doctype

Tags: html, emmet

He estado haciendo pruebas con emmet para crear una página completa con abreviaciones de emmet.

En un principio hice esto, pero no quedé satisfecho ya que el título de la página era el predefinido y el html lang estaba en inglés:

```html
html:5>form:post[action="aplicacion.php"]>(fieldset>legend{Únete}+p{Nuestros socios tienen muchas ventajas. ¡Y es gratis!}+ul>li>label[for="nombre"]{Nombre y apellidos: }+input:text[id="nombre" autofocus required name="nombre"]^li>label[for="comentario"]{Comentario: }+textarea[id="comentario" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu comentario" rows="2" name="comentario"])+(fieldset>legend{Campos de entrada de texto especiales}+ul>li>label[for="contra"]{Contraseña}+input:password[required id="contra" name="contra"]^li>label[for="buscar"]{Buscar[HTML5]: }+input:search[id="buscar" name="buscar"]^li>label[for="email"]{Email[HTML5]: }+input:email[id="email" name="email"]^li>label[for="telf"]{Teléfono [HTML5]: }+input:tel[id="telf" name="telf"]^li>label[for="url"]{URL [HTML5]: }+input:url[id="url" name="url"])+input:submit[value="Enviar" name="enviar"]
```

por lo que seguí intentando

Lo más cerca que me quedé de mi resultado fue hacerlo en dos veces, por un lado poner el !doctype y por otro el resto de la web, el resultado fue este:

```html
!!!
html[lang="es"]>head>title{Ejercicio 2}+meta[charset="UTF-8"]+meta[name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"]+meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"]^body>form:post[action="aplicacion.php"]>(fieldset>legend{Únete}+p{Nuestros socios tienen muchas ventajas. ¡Y es gratis!}+ul>li>label[for="nombre"]{Nombre y apellidos: }+input:text[id="nombre" autofocus required name="nombre"]^li>label[for="comentario"]{Comentario: }+textarea[id="comentario" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu comentario" rows="2" name="comentario"])+(fieldset>legend{Campos de entrada de texto especiales}+ul>li>label[for="contra"]{Contraseña}+input:password[required id="contra" name="contra"]^li>label[for="buscar"]{Buscar[HTML5]: }+input:search[id="buscar" name="buscar"]^li>label[for="email"]{Email[HTML5]: }+input:email[id="email" name="email"]^li>label[for="telf"]{Teléfono [HTML5]: }+input:tel[id="telf" name="telf"]^li>label[for="url"]{URL [HTML5]: }+input:url[id="url" name="url"])+input:submit[value="Enviar" name="enviar"]
```

Existe alguna forma de unificar todo eso en un sólo comando emmet? Gracias de antemano